# Webpack - Extract-text-plugin and Less-loader won't render

Tags: webpack

I'm using this configuration in webpack and the result is not correct for some reasons.

Webpack less loader config:

```
{
  test: /\.less$/,
  loader: ExtractTextPlugin.extract('style-loader', 'css-loader?sourceMap', 'less-loader')
}
```

Less file content:

```
@var-color: #000;

.app {
    padding: 20px;
    background-color: @var-color;
    border: 1px solid blue;
}
```

And the result:

```
@var-color: #000;.app{padding:20px;background-color:@var-color;border:1px solid blue}
```

Note I need all those loader in that order.

Any help?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I don't believe ExtractTextPlugin.extract takes a third argument. I believe you have to chain together loaders using Webpack's terrible `!` syntax.

```
ExtractTextPlugin.extract('style-loader', 'css-loader?sourceMap!less-loader')
```

Comment: Why is that? is there any particular reason for this?

Comment: I don't know. Webpack has confusing source code, bad API design, and terrible documentation. It's unfortunate that Webpack is such a useful tool!

Comment: Definitely you're right, the lack of a good documentation is just unbelievable!

Comment: So it turns out the first parameter is the fallback!

Comment: Use webpack 2 which is stable now, it has a better configuration, even though you might face similar problems.